# ubuntu boot stick black screens after removing python3, what should i do?

Tags: 17.04

Ubuntu 16.04 has gone to debian system & showing black desktop and cross pointer after removing python3,what should I do?

Comment: Did you really remove Python 3 completely? There's no Python 3 on your system anymore at all?

Comment: Yes , now in the after opening laptop it's showing debian system at booting window

Comment: Well, there's your answer....

Answer (score 1):

You destroyed your system beyond easy repair.

Essential system components, including apt, use Python3. DO NOT remove or alter the system-provided version of Python2 and Python3 - your system requires those.

1. Use a LiveUSB to backup your data to some other media.
2. Then reinstall.